# C printf behaves very strange

Tags: c, printf

so this is what's going on:

```
int onesCount = ones(num);
printf("Number 0x%x has %d ones.\n", num, onesCount);
```

Outputs for the number 15:

```
Number 0xa has 0 ones.
```

But if I change the printf to this:

```
int onesCount = ones(num);

printf("Number 0x%x has", num);
printf(" %d ones.\n", onesCount);
```

it outputs for the number 15:

```
Number 0xa has 4 ones.
```

Generally, if I printf only `onesCount` it outputs the correct value. If I printf it with other variable, it prints 0. Any idea?

Comment: show `ones()`..

Comment: `Number 0xa has 4 ones.`...umm..how?

Comment: There is no problem in the ones() function. As I've said, it returns correct value. If I print it, it prints correctly. 
And if I initialize onesCount to any other value, without calling ones(), it displays 0 anyway.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Sorry, I meant number 15, I did not copy-paste the exact output, my bad. But the problem remains.

Comment: num is unsigned long long, ones() returns int

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not clairvoyants here, meaning that we cannot telepathically guess how your `num` is declared. But an educated guess would be that format `%x` does not match the type of your `num`. What you observe is a typical manifestation of *undefined behavior* caused by format mismatch.

---

As you stated in the comments your `num` is `unsigned long long`. You cannot print an `unsigned long long` using `%x` format. `%x` can only be used with `unsigned int`. For `unsigned long long` you would need `%llx`.

Comment: num is unsigned long long, ones() returns int.

Comment: @Bondy Tip: in the future, put important information like `num` is `unsigned long long` in the initial post.

Comment: Though I wonder, why does it work for a single variable printf, even with the missmatched data type?

Comment: @Bondy: Variadic parameters of `printf` (or any other variadic function) are like a continuous binary stream that `printf` parses by using your format string for guidance. The moment you "lie" to `printf` about the next piece of data in that stream, the whole parsing process gets derailed. It kinda "goes out of sync". All *subsequent* "reads" from that binary stream become misaligned/invalid.

Comment: In your first example the aforementioned misalignment begins at `num`. For that reason the subsequent argument `onesCount` is read incorrectly. In your second example each `printf` has only one argument. The damage just does not get a chance to manifest itself.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was very helpful!

Comment: @Bondy: it doesn't work with the printf which just shows one value. It only looks like it works. If you try it with a very big value in `num` you will see the problem. What you are seeing is a manifestation of the fact that your hardware is little-endian.